# How to fix invisible Settings window in GNOME 3 with Wayland?

Tags: debian, gnome3, wayland

I'm running Gnome 3 on Debian testing. So far two applications are affected: totem ("Videos") and Settings. When I try to open one or the other, the icon appears in the status bar below, but no window appears on the screen. Things I tried so far:

- Searched online, "gnome 3 window invisible", "gnome 3 find my window" (in case it was somewhere outside the visible area), "gnome 3 settings window invisible", nothing helped so far; most answers were old, from 2015 or 2017.
- Followed https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-lost.html.en – the window icon does **not** appear when I press Meta+TAB. It only appears on the status bar.
- Deleted `.config/dconf/user` and `~/.config/gnome-session` and restarted the computer.

I finally found a workaround: to log out and log in again, using the "Gnome 3 Xorg" profile. I can reliably reproduce the problem: if I log in using Wayland, the Settings window does not appear. If I log in using Xorg, the window is there.

I can keep using the workaround of course, but since I have a reproducible case, how would I go about further diagnosing this?